# SQL Server Deployed SSIS package won't open files despite SA account having access to folder

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms, sql-server-agent

I posted a similar question before, but I have now came back to the point where I need to deal with this and after some tuning I have managed to get rid of all the errors, except one warning that basically tells me that the path provided to the package not finding any files in the directory (which is false). This almost makes me want to believe this is again a permissions issue. As when I run the package locally it all works fine. Here is the warning:
[image]
Same message appears when I right click SSIS package under the catalogue and directly try to execute the job.
I made sure that the caller has full permissions to the folder in question

[image]

SQL Server Agent Job calls the job like so [image]

With a single step in it to execute the SSIS package from the catalogue:
[image]

The history of the executions is all successful and the history of SQL Agent job is all green 
One of the suggestions I got was to open SQL Server Configuration manager but I don't appear to have access to that. I am new to this whole process so I am not sure if authentication has something to do with it or the sa account's permissions. 
Note: I am working on this on a remote dev server and not directly on my pc. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The permissions need to be applied to the SQL Server Agent Service Account or its per-service SID.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Alright, I have no clue (yet) how to get there, some links would help a lot, but I will do some research on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the database instance was on a whole different server that I wasn't even given access to. That server obviously didn't have the path specified in the SSIS package, so what I had to do is create a folder for files in the correct server, reroute my files there, and change the SSIS package path after obtaining the access to the server where DB instance lives. Me being new to all this, it was absolute frustration especially since our team is small and I am new in it I can't just ask someone questions about this all the time. Hopefully this will save someone a lot of time.

Comment: _I can't just ask someone questions about this all the time_ Yes, you can and you should. People new to a team are expected to ask questions - how else do they learn?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're running the package as the Agent Service Account:

[image]

The permissions need to be applied to the SQL Server Agent Service Account or its per-service SID.

You can see the service account with PowerShell like this:

```
PS C:\Users\david> (Get-WmiObject win32_service | where Name -eq "SQLSERVERAGENT").StartName
NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT
```

Comment: It tells me that term "NT" Cant be recognized

Comment: The command is `(Get-WmiObject win32_service | where Name -eq "SQLSERVERAGENT").StartName`  "NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT" is the output on my workstation.

Comment: Alright that's what I thought but on my pc the output is just nothing

Comment: If you installed a named instance the service will have a different name. eg `(Get-WmiObject win32_service | where Name -eq 'SQLAgent$SQL2017').StartName`